# Two prime numbers equals even number

Tags: c++, primes

Given an even number n>2, find prime numbers, whose sum is n. Must use function which finds prime nubmers.

Maybe can start something like this? :

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
{
    if (IsPrime(i) && IsPrime(n - i))
        break;
}
```

Comment: Yup, sounds like a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Yes, this algorithm should work

Comment: Hint: do you really need to iterate to `n`?

Comment: You need to write the `IsPrime()` function yourself? I would suggest the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It's not the most elegant solution, but it's pretty easy to understand, and one that *every* learning programmer will write at some point. Fill up a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with all the primes less than `n`, then walk through the list from the bottom, and for every prime `p<n/2`, check if `n-p` is in the list. (This is not necessarily the "best" way to do this, but it's ok for a beginner).

Comment: The first step is to prove Goldbach's conjecture which is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Only if it's a constructive proof. Just knowing the 2 primes exist won't really help here.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - Fortunately, the `break` statement and the Goldbach's conjecture prevent the loop from iterating to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me..

```
public ArrayList<Integer> primesum(int A) {

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(A < 2)
        return result;

    int first = 2;
    int second = A - first; 
    while(first <= second){
        second = A - first;

        if(isPrime(second) == true && isPrime(first)){
            result.add(first);
            result.add(second);
            return result;
        }
        first++;
    }

    return result;

}


public boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return false;
    for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a homework, So i will give you tips to start up with:

1) To check whether a number N is prime, you can iterate till N/2 and break if you find its multiple. A nested for-loop would be the easiest solution if you don't bother much with space and time complexities.

Comment: There is a lower limit that N/2 which will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I give you just an hint, not the entire solution, that will be the starting point!

This is one of the possible solution, not THE solution:

First of all, define a function that check if a number is prime:

```
bool isPrime(const unsigned& number) {
  for (unsigned i = 2; i < number; i++) {
     if (number % i == 0) {
       return false;
     }
   }
  return true;
 }
```

Define also:

```
struct PrimeSum {
  unsigned first;
  unsigned second; 
 };

PrimeSum searchPrimeAddend(const unsigned& number, const vector<unsigned>& v) {
   // your code to find two number iterating the vector 
}
```

In your main:

```
int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  const unsigned N = 13;
  std::vector<unsigned> primeList;
  for (unsigned i = 3; i < N; i += 2) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
       primeList.push_back(i);
    }
  }
 PrimeSum primes = searchPrimeAddend(N, primeList);
}
```

Comment: Just a small nitpick: your `isPrime` function will not detect 2 as prime, when it is. However for the purposes of *this* assignment it doesn't matter since *all other* prime numbers are odd and the sum of an even an an odd is always odd.

Answer (score 0):

This works and it is C++

```
bool isPrime(int number){
    if (number == 1)
        return false;

    if (number == 2)
        return true;

    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; ++i)
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

vector<int> Solution::primesum(int A) {    
    std::vector<int> vect;
    int pivot = A / 2; // the prime numbers cannot cross each other in the middle

    // keep j less than the i. i will be the lower bound of the number and
    // j will be the higher bound
    int j = A-2;
    for (int i = 2; i <= pivot && j >= pivot; i++, j--){
        if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(j)){
            vect.push_back(i);
            vect.push_back(j);
            return vect;
        }
    }

    return vect;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

pseudo code

- find all primes up to n and fill a container (ordered by insert or by container)
- for the container get forward iterator 'up' and reverse iterator 'down'
- while (up!=end && down!=rend && *up<=*down)

  - sum = *up + *down
  - if sum == n

    - save pair  // found
    - ++up
  - else if sum > n

    - ++down
  - else if sum < n

    - ++up

this leaves some C++ homework to you

different solution (probably more efficient for a single run)

- find all primes up to n/2 and fill a container (ordered by insert or by container)
- for the container get forward iterator 'up'
- while (up!=end)

  - other = n - *up
  - if is_prime(other)

    - save pair *up, other
  - ++up